# If $0<r\neq 1$ and $U$ is convex then $\partial U\cap\partial (rU)=\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be convex and closed. I'm trying to find conditions for which the following happens:

> If $0<r\neq 1$ then $\partial U\cap\partial (rU)=\emptyset$.

It seems to me that this is not true if $0$ is in the frontier of $U$, for instance $U=\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ or $U=\{(x,y):y\ge |x|\}$. In fact, in both examples $U=rU$.

So, let us suppose that $0\in\text{Int} (U)$. Does this suffice to prove that $\partial U\cap\partial (rU)=\emptyset$? I couldn't find counterexamples so far.

What do you think?

Thank you.

Comment: By "frontier of $U$" do you mean the boundary $$\partial U \equiv \overline U\cap \overline {\mathbb R^n\setminus U}\ \mathrm ?$$

Comment: @Math1000 yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG assume that $r>1$ (if $0<r<1$ then let $U' = rU$ and $r' = \frac{1}{r}$, so $r'U' = U$ and $r'>1$). Suppose that the intersection is nonempty. Then, there is some $x\in \partial (rU)$ such that $x\in\partial U$. Since $x\in \partial (rU)$, $y = r^{-1}x\in \partial U$. Thus, both $x$ and $y$ are on the boundary of $U$. We can draw a line segment from $0$ through $x$, which will also pass through $y$. If $0\in\text{Int}(U)$ there is an open neighborhood of $0$ also in $\text{Int}(U)$ since the interior is always open. Then, take the collection of line segments (not including endpoints) from points in that neighborhood to $x$. The union $I$ of all these line segments is an open set containing $y$. Since $U$ is convex, $I\subset U$. Thus, there is an open subset of $U$ containing $y$, contradicting that $y\in\partial U$. Thus, if $0\in\text{Int}(U)$ then the intersection must be empty.

If $0\notin\text{Int}(U)$ then $0 \in \partial U$ or $0 \in \text{Ext}(U)$. If $0\in\partial U$ then obviously $0 \in \partial (rU)$ so the intersection will be nonempty. If $0 \in \text{Ext}(U)$, then let the shortest distance between $0$ and $U$ be $R$ and the largest distance be $M$. If $0<r<\frac{R}{M}$, then $rU\cap U = \emptyset$. However, if $U$ is a line segment not through the origin, then $rU\cap U = \emptyset$ for all $r\neq 1$.

Thus, $\partial U \cap \partial (rU) = \emptyset$ for all $r$ if $0\in\text{Int}(U)$ and $\partial U \cap \partial (rU) \neq \emptyset$ for all $r$ if $0\in \partial U$.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. Are you sure you meant $I$ is the intersection of the line segments joining points of the neighborhood to $x$? Seems to me their intersection is just the point $x$. Didn't you want to mean the union? Also, $x$ is not an interior point so it's not open. Maybe you wanted to say $y$ is an interior point of $I$?

Comment: Yes, I meant the union of line segments not including their endpoints, so that $x\notin I$. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach
that seems promising to me
but I can't push it through.
I'll enter it here
in the hope that
someone else can complete it.

$\partial U$
can be described as
$(t, f(t))$
for
$0 \le t \lt 2\pi$.

Suppose $(0, 0) \in U$ \
$\partial U$.

Suppose
$\partial U \cap \partial(rU) \ne \emptyset$
where $0 < r < 1$.

Then there are
$a, b \in [0, 2\pi)$
 such that
$(a, f(a)) = r(b, f(b))$
so that
$a = rb$ and
$f(a) = rf(b)$.

Consider the line from
$(b, f(b))$
to
$(rb, rf(b))$.
This has equation
$c(b, f(b))+(1-c)(rb, rf(b))$
for $c \in \mathbb{R}$
or

$c(b-rb, f(b)-rf(b))+(rb, rf(b))\\
=c(1-r)(b, f(b))+r(b, f(b))\\
=c(1-r)(b, f(b))+(a, f(a))
$.

Frustrating.
I can't see where
this leads to a contradiction.
What I would like to do
is show that this line
which passes through
two points on
$\partial U$
also passes through
a third point,
which would be a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm still trying to grasp why there "must" be a third point, though...

Comment: Because the line goes inside the contract set and so must leave it. But I'm not able to find a proof to match that intuition.